# iOS Today extension crash : removing inactive plug-in <PKPersonality>

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ios8-today-widget

[image]

I have set up Crashlytics for my app and I get these crash reports for a lot of users but I have no idea what is causing this. There is no information about this on the web either. Does anyone have any idea? Please..

Comment: I just started getting same crash via HockeyApp for my iOS keyboard extension. No idea.

Comment: Started to receive these too. From what the crash says ("removing in-active plugin") I don't think it's harmful. But that would be a weird way to unload a widget.